# How do I create field with Bool type for Record Type?

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

When I try to add a new field to record type, there is no possibility to add a Bool type. How can I do this anyway?

[image]

Comment: `Int(64)` - 1 is true, 0 is false.

Comment: and no other solutions? Only via Int?

Comment: Well, you *could* use any of the datatypes with two specific values, but Int is the clearest and simplest one.

Comment: ok, thank you. How is it possible, that there is no Bool type?

Answer (score 12):

Referring to [Creating a Database Schema by Saving Records](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/CreatingaSchemabySavingRecords/CreatingaSchemabySavingRecords.html) Apple Documentation, the following table contains CloudKit possible field types:

[image]

unfortunately, there is no Bool type found. What I find -logically- is the most suitable to be a replacement of Bool is the `Int(64)`, because:

Int(64) class -as mentioned in the table- is [NSNumber](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsnumber) which has a `boolValue` which returns a Swift Bool:

> The number object's value expressed as a Boolean value. A 0 value
>   always means false, and any nonzero value is interpreted as true.

For more details, check the *NSNumber* documentation.

Which leads to the ease of treating them as Bool inside your application. For example:

```
let myFalseNumber:NSNumber = 0.0
let myTrueNumber:NSNumber = 0.01232
let anotherTrueNumber: NSNumber = -99

print(myFalseNumber.boolValue) // false
print(myTrueNumber.boolValue) // true
print(anotherTrueNumber.boolValue) // true
```

Although both `Int(64)` and `Double` are treated as NSNumber, the reason why choosing `Int(64)` instead of `Double` (CloudKit Type) is the generality of treating "1 if true and 0 if false" (without any floating points). For more information, you might want to check [Boolean data type - Generalities (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_data_type#Generalities).

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Bool type available for CKRecord.The best option is Int(64).

[Source Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/cloudkit/ckrecord#2166530)